# JSTL tag highlighting in NetBeans 8

Tags: netbeans, jstl, syntax-highlighting, highlight, highlighting

Is there a way to make NetBeans 8 highlight opening and closing JSTL tags like it does with opening and closing HTML tags? For example, highlight the opening  and closing  when cursor is on them:

```
<c:if test="${actionBean == 'Test'}">

<div>Test</div>

</c:if>
```

[image: only highlights opening JSTL tag]

[image: highlights opening and closing tags of HTML element]

Comment: `JSTL` tags support what you want to do.

Comment: @Afsun Khammadli how? See my edit with screenshots for clarity. As you can see, Netbeans only highlights the JTSL tag that is focused with cursor. For HTML it highlights both the open and closing tags. I want it to be able to highlight both open and closing JSTL tags.